# Using jQuery, can you paste a rectangle by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If you are using jQuery and have a CSS class called `.draggable_rectangle`, how can you create a button that will draw a copy of the rectangle each time the user clicks the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button id="copy_rectangle"></button>
<script>
$("#copy_retangle").click(function(){
  $(".draggable_rectangle").clone().appendTo("body");
  // add extra code to make it draggable
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Haochi: I adapted your code. But when I press the button, there is no second rectangle, and I can't move the original rectangle anymore.

Comment: @Haochi: Can I name the rectangles "rectangle1", rectangle2", or something?

Comment: @Winston It's because I misspelled rectangle in the above code. Check out this [code here](http://jsfiddle.net/haochi/UaVMq/).

Comment: @Haochi: Thank you for the code and for introducing me to jsfiddle. Sorry to bother you. I added a class called ".draggable_rectangle". How do I make all the rectangles draggable?

Comment: @Winston I will just point you [jQueryUI's Draggable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). Look at the examples. If you need more help on that you should probably open a as that's an entirely different question.